# How to make a specific view not inherit from application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have one specific view that I don't want to "inherit" the code from `layouts/application.html.erb`. How should it do this?

One way to do this is to include in `application.html.erb`:

```
<% except current_page?(page_path) %>
  content
<% end %>
```

But it feels to me more like something you should specify in the specific view. What would be the convention for this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one action, you can try:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  def method_name
    render :layout => 'another_layout'
  end
end
```

For all actions in controller, you can do:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController
  layout 'another_layout'

  #action methods here
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want a layout to apply to a specific action you can disable layout rendering at the controller level. For example if you want `MyController#some_action` view to not be rendered within the layout, you can do this:

```
class MyContorller < ApplicationController
  def some_action
    # Your logic here
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

This way your view (`app/views/my_controller/some_action.html.erb`) doesn't inherit from the `application.html.erb` and is rendered containing only what's inside the view file. For more information on rendering you can take a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

Answer (score 1):

For selected actions you can try like this ......

```
class MyContorller < ApplicationController
  layout 'other_layout_name', only: [:method_1, :method_2, :method_4] 

  #action methods here
end
```